# Get List<Segment> from a PathGeometry

Tags: c#, canvas, shapes

I draw in a canvas several shapes. I have two kinds of shapes : Ellipse, and Path.

Now when I make a click on my Canvas, I want to get the nearest Shape.

I could manage to do something for Ellipse, but for Path I don't manage to find how to get its coordinates.

Here is the code I use to generate a List, in case something is not optimum in that method :

Concretely, "percage" are drillings, if Type=12, it means I draw a slot(Path). else I draw a circle(Ellipse)

```
if (percage.Type == 12)
{
    double r = percage.Diametre / 2;
    LineSegment ligne1 = new LineSegment();
    LineSegment ligne2 = new LineSegment();
    Point ptCentre = new Point(dx + percage.Coor_X, this.MyScrollViewer.ActualHeight * echelle - dy - percage.Coor_Y);
    double angle = percage.AnglePer;
    double xLeft = ptCentre.X - r;
    double xRight = ptCentre.X + r;
    double yUp = ptCentre.Y - ((percage.Longueur / 2) - r);
    double yDown = ptCentre.Y + ((percage.Longueur / 2) - r);
    Point pt1 = new Point(xLeft, yUp);
    Point pt2 = new Point(xRight, yUp);
    Point pt3 = new Point(xRight, yDown);
    Point pt4 = new Point(xLeft, yDown);
    pt1 = Global.RotatePoint(pt1, ptCentre, angle - 90);
    pt2 = Global.RotatePoint(pt2, ptCentre, angle - 90);
    pt3 = Global.RotatePoint(pt3, ptCentre, angle - 90);
    pt4 = Global.RotatePoint(pt4, ptCentre, angle - 90);

    Path arc_path1 = new Path();
    arc_path1.Stroke = Brushes.Red;
    arc_path1.StrokeThickness = 2;
    PathGeometry pathGeometry = new PathGeometry();
    ArcSegment arc1 = new ArcSegment();
    ArcSegment arc2 = new ArcSegment();
    PathFigure pathfigure1 = new PathFigure();
    PathFigure pathfigure2 = new PathFigure();
    arc1.Point = new Point(pt2.X, pt2.Y);
    arc1.Point = new Point(pt4.X, pt4.Y);
    pathfigure1.StartPoint = new Point(pt1.X, pt1.Y);
    pathfigure1.StartPoint = new Point(pt3.X, pt3.Y);
    SweepDirection sd = SweepDirection.Counterclockwise;
    if (yUp < yDown)
    {
        sd = SweepDirection.Clockwise;
    }
    arc1.Size = new Size(r, r);
    arc1.SweepDirection = sd;
    arc2.Size = new Size(r, r);
    arc2.SweepDirection = sd;
    arc1.Point = pt2;
    arc2.Point = pt4;
    ligne1.Point = new Point(pt3.X, pt3.Y);
    ligne2.Point = new Point(pt1.X, pt1.Y);
    pathfigure1.StartPoint = new Point(pt1.X, pt1.Y);
    pathfigure1.Segments.Add(arc1);
    pathfigure1.Segments.Add(ligne1);
    pathfigure1.Segments.Add(arc2);
    pathfigure1.Segments.Add(ligne2);
    pathGeometry.Figures.Add(pathfigure1);
    arc_path1.Data = pathGeometry;
    arc_path1.Tag = percage;

    percage.ListShapes.Add(arc_path1);

}
else
{
    Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse();
    ellipse.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red;
    ellipse.StrokeThickness = 1;
    ellipse.Fill = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Red);
    ellipse.Width = percage.Diametre;
    ellipse.Height = percage.Diametre;
    percage.Coor_X_Graph = X1 + dx - (percage.Diametre / 2);
    percage.Coor_Y_Graph = this.MyScrollViewer.ActualHeight * echelle - (Y1 + dy) - (percage.Diametre / 2);
    ellipse.Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness(percage.Coor_X_Graph, percage.Coor_Y_Graph, 0, 0);
    ellipse.Tag = percage;

    percage.ListShapes.Add(ellipse);
}
```

Then, to get the nearest shape, I began that code :
For ellipse I can retrieve its coordinates, but for Path, couldn't find the List of Segments inside.

```
StartPoint = e.GetPosition(monDessin);
double distance=-1;
Shape selectedShape = null;
for (int i = monDessin.Children.Count - 1; i > -1; i--)
{

    if (monDessin.Children[i] is Ellipse)
    {
        Ellipse ell = (Ellipse)monDessin.Children[i];
        double x = ell.Margin.Left + Width / 2;
        double y = ell.Margin.Top - ell.Height / 2;
        double dist = Math.Sqrt((StartPoint.X - x) * (StartPoint.X - x) + (StartPoint.Y -y) * (StartPoint.Y - y));
        if(distance==-1 || dist<distance)
        {
            distance = dist;
        }
    }
    else if(monDessin.Children[i] is Path)
    {
        Path path=(Path)monDessin.Children[i];
        Geometry geometry = path.Data;
        foreach(PathFigure pf in ?????)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I could do it myself looking a bit more on internet (not sure it is the best way as I began on that theme,so any other suggestion is welcome)

I found some "solution" [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/380f5073-53d3-4e98-9b9c-a863db016995/problem-getting-pathgeometry-object-from-path-programmatically?forum=wpf)
But the code didn't work, got an error on the following line (without understand why, neither what it does)

```
string value = seralizer.ConvertToString(geomerty, null);
```

Finally I adapted it looking on msdn website, I found [geometry.GetOutlinedPathGeometry()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.media.geometry(v=vs.110).aspx) and [pathGeometry.Figures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pathgeometry.figures(v=vs.110).aspx) that allowed to get list of figures. I just don't understand why all my ArcSegment became BezierSegment.
Anyway, it works fine, so I put here the code :

```
StartPoint = e.GetPosition(monDessin);
double distance=-1;
double dist;
Shape selectedShape = null;
for (int i = monDessin.Children.Count - 1; i > -1; i--)
{
    string type = monDessin.Children[i].GetType().ToString();

    if (monDessin.Children[i] is Ellipse)
    {
        Ellipse ell = (Ellipse)monDessin.Children[i];
        double x = ell.Margin.Left + ell.Width / 2;
        double y = ell.Margin.Top - ell.Height / 2;
        dist = Math.Sqrt((StartPoint.X - x) * (StartPoint.X - x) + (StartPoint.Y -y) * (StartPoint.Y - y));
        if(distance==-1 || dist<distance)
        {
            distance = dist;
        }
    }
    else if(monDessin.Children[i] is Path)
        {
            Path path=(Path)monDessin.Children[i];
            string titi = path.Tag.GetType().ToString();
            Geometry geometry = path.Data;
            PathGeometry pathGeometry = geometry.GetOutlinedPathGeometry();
            PathFigureCollection figures = pathGeometry.Figures;
            if (figures != null)
            {
               foreach (PathFigure figure in figures)
               {
                   foreach (PathSegment segment in figure.Segments)
                   {
                       //first syntax : if(segment is LineSegment)
                       if(segment is LineSegment)
                       {
                          LineSegment lineSegment = (LineSegment)segment;
                          double x = lineSegment.Point.X;
                          ouble y = lineSegment.Point.Y;
                       }
                       //2nd syntax : 
                       //ArcSegment arcSegment = segment as ArcSegment;
                       //Then check if not null
                       ArcSegment arcSegment = segment as ArcSegment;
                       if (arcSegment != null)
                       {
                           double x = arcSegment.Point.X;
                           double y = arcSegment.Point.Y;
                           dist = Math.Sqrt((StartPoint.X - x) * (StartPoint.X - x) + (StartPoint.Y - y) * (StartPoint.Y - y));
                           if (distance == -1 || dist < distance)
                           {
                               distance = dist;
                           }
                       }
                       BezierSegment bezierSegment = segment as BezierSegment;
                       if (bezierSegment != null)
                       {
                           double x = bezierSegment.Point3.X;
                           double y = bezierSegment.Point3.Y;
                           dist = Math.Sqrt((StartPoint.X - x) * (StartPoint.X - x) + (StartPoint.Y - y) * (StartPoint.Y - y));
                           if (distance == -1 || dist < distance)
                           {
                                distance = dist;
                           }
                       }
                   }
              }
          }
     }
}
```

Nota : I found two different syntaxes to check the type of segment(i.e LineSegment), I don't know which is the best approach, the first syntax seems better, but the 2nd one has the advantage to check if it is null(even if in theory it may never happen???)